# How can I see the console output when running tests with NCrunch?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, ncrunch

I don't know if it's implemented but there is an option for NCrunch output in the 
Output window.

[image]

TestDriven.NET is already doing this while you are running the tests and I realized it was useful when trying out things quickly. Is there a way to make it work in NCrunch?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check the NCrunch Tests window. I had the same issue, but then noticed that the Tests window is displaying output from my `Console.WriteLine` calls.